# How to pass extra value to given field's process_formdata method in WTForms

Tags: python, forms, wtforms

I have custom ZIPCodeField, but it require country to be given to work properly,
it's easy for validation where i can just save it in _country attribute of the form in form's **init**(with fallback to country field in the same form), it looks like:

```
class ZIPCodeField(wtforms.TextField):
    def pre_validate(self, form):
        if not self.data:
            return

        country = country = getattr(form, '_country', form.data.get('country'))
        country = country.upper()

        if not validate_zip_code(self.data, country):
            raise ValueError(self.gettext(u'Invalid ZIP code.'))
```

but there is a problem with for process_formdata method (where I want to pass the received data trough simple filter to format the ZIP code correctly), we have no form instance, so seems like there are 2 solutions:

Saving country on field level, like:

```
class ZIPCodeField(wtforms.TextField):

    def process_formdata(self, valuelist):
    if valuelist:
        self.data = format_zip_code(valuelist[0], self._country)
    else:
        self.data = ''

class TestForm(wtforms.Form):
    zip_code = ZIPCodeField()

form = TestForm(MultiDict([('zip_code', '123455')]))
form.zip_code._country = u'US'
```

Or, overide process method and pass my extra value to it's data argument, like:

```
class ZIPCodeField(wtforms.TextField):
    def process(self, formdata, data):
         # we picking country value from data here
         pass 

form = TestForm(MultiDict([('zip_code', '123455')]),
     zip_code=zip_code={'country': u'US'})
```

Which of these is proper solution? or there is better solution?

Answer (score 0):

All of them will work but in general I would advise you too keep data access logic out of your forms. This makes for a bad separation of concerns.

You forms have a very specific job and that is to validate the form submission. In your case you want to augment the data submitted in form then validate it. This doesn't require any overriding of wtforms `process` methods. I would do the country retrieval either in a middleware or in the view, append it to the form's submission data, then validate the form as normal.  If the zipcode didn't return a valid country or wasn't found I would `abort(400)` right there.